# Completing the star pattern

Tags: java

I was unable to print the complete star pattern. I want to print

```
       *
      * *
 * * * * * * *
  * *     * *
   *       *
  * *     * *
 * * * * * * *
      * *
       *
```

Problem with my code is I cannot figure out how to print first part of 4th and 5th row.
My code:

```
    //print A
       int i, j, k = 0,n=2;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        // Print spaces
        for (j = 7; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // Print *
        while (k != (2 * i - 1)) {
            if (k == 0 || k == 2 * i - 2)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
            k++;
            ;
        }
        k = 0;

        // print next row
        System.out.println(); 
    }

//print middle line
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
    System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();




//print V
int hight=2;
int rowLen = (hight-1)*2;

for(i=0; i<hight; i++){


    //print space
    for(int s=11;s>hight;s--)
    {

        {
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    //print *
    int start = i;
    int end = rowLen-i;
    for(j=0;j<=rowLen; j++){
        if(j==end){
            System.out.println("*");
            break;
        }
        else if(j==start){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

    }

}




for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
    if(i==1 || i==3 || i==9 || i==11)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    }
System.out.println();   




//print middle line
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
    System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();




        //print V
int hight1=2;
int rowLen1 = (hight1-1)*2;

for(i=0; i<hight1; i++){


    //print space
    for(int s=7;s>hight1;s--)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }


    //print *
    int start1 = i;
    int end1 = rowLen1-i;
    for(j=0;j<=rowLen1; j++){
        if(j==end1){
            System.out.println("*");
            break;
        }
        else if(j==start1){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

    }

}
```

Using the above code i was able to get this o/p

```
       *
      * *
 * * * * * * *
          * *
           *
  * *     * *
 * * * * * * *
      * *
       *
```

What code should be added to line 46-52 to complete the star. Also if possible please tell if my code meet the programming standards. I am a rookie though.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
//print V
int hight=2;
int rowLen = (hight-1)*2;

for (i=0; i<hight; i++) {

    for (int zz=0;zz<=i;zz++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int zy=i-1;zy<=0;zy++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    //print space
    for (int s=0;s<=3+i;s++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    //print *
```

As to standards, you'll find most people put the start curly brace on the same line as the `if`, `for`, ...  At least be consistent.  I removed the unnecessary  block you had inside your `//print space` loop.  If you do leave the block in the code, the line of code in the block should be indented.

Comment: I agree, adopt a style and be consistent --
 https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style -- inconsistencies here in this answer are spacing: `for(){` vs `for () {` I'm in the _always use spaces_ camp: always `while (condition) {` never `while(condition){` I have historical reasons for preferring "Allman Style" bracing.

Comment: @ShaneCoder Yes!

Comment: If you are following a standard, then you should follow a Java standard.  Java standards all say that there should be spaces around infix operators.  And *any* coding standard worth the paper that it is written on should say that correct spelling is preferred.  (What is a "hight"?)